# "Snap to" shortcuts don't work in 2.8/2.9

Tags: shortcut, customization

I'm really not sure what has changed in 2.8 with regard to how this menu's shortcuts are handled, but the way I had customized shortcuts for the **Snap to** elements in 2.79 is no longer working in recent versions. (I'm using 2.9.0)

The menu in question:

[image]

My 2.79 configuration (working):

[image]

My identical 2.9.0 configuration (*not* working):

[image]

The goal is to set the following shortcuts:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> Snap to: Increment
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> Snap to: Vertex
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>2</kbd> Snap to: Edge
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> Snap to: Face
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>4</kbd> Snap to: volume

I placed the shortcut definitions in the same place as in 2.79: **3D View (Global)**

The Python names and syntax appear not to have changed. I checked them in Blender's Console.

Also, I consulted [the current Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ToolSettings.html#bpy.types.ToolSettings.ToolSettings.snap_elements), but it didn't give any clues about shortcut assignment.

Note that although <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> through <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> now have Hide Collection assigned by default, disabling these does not solve the problem of my custom shortcuts not working.

I'm perplexed... any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now have the possibility to snap on multiple elements (ie vertices and faces simultaneously).

[image]

So the attribute is:

```
tool_settings.snap_elements #With 's'
```

And the value is a set, ie:

```
{'INCREMENT'}
```

[image]

Comment: You made my day! Thanks a million.  :-)